# Function pointer call doesn't compile

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, function-pointers

I just dont get it, why line 22 is failing to compile?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "Library.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        void* libHandle = 0;

        libHandle = dlopen("libExpandableTestLibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!libHandle)
            throw std::logic_error(dlerror());

        std::cout << "Libary opened gracefully" << std::endl;

        void* fuPtr = 0;
        fuPtr = dlsym(libHandle, "createLibrary");
        if(!fuPtr)
                throw std::logic_error(dlerror());

        Library* libInstance = static_cast<Library* ()>(fuPtr)();
        // Tutorial: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687
        // Tutorial Code: shape *my_shape = static_cast<shape *()>(mkr)();
        // Compiler error message:  Application.cpp:22:56: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘Library*()’
        libInstance->Foo();

        dlclose(libHandle);

    } catch(std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Any help is welcome
If you need additional information's just let me know.

Comment: Try a `reinterpret_cast` - `void*` and other casts don't mix.

Comment: @JohnDibling, it's inline in the code...

Comment: @Nim: not quite. to cast from `void*` to any other object pointer type (that was maybe previously implicitly converted to the `void*`) the proper way is a `static_cast`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, with an object pointer possibly, but a function pointer too?

Comment: For people coming here wanting to create their dynamic class loading code, check this single-header library: https://github.com/davidalbertonogueira/CrossPlatfDynamicLibraryPlugInArchitecture
@Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of said lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it that `fuPtr` points to a function that is supposed to return a pointer to a `Library` object (given the name loaded is `"createLibrary"`).

In that case, the line including your cast needs to look like this:

```
Library* libInstance = reinterpret_cast<Library* (*)()>(fuPtr)();
```

Comment: This doesn't work either as in that case you have to use reinterpret_cast however, you pointed me to the correct solution. Thanks in advance. Solution: Library* libInstance = reinterpret_cast<Library* (*)()>(fuPtr)();

Comment: Ah.  Not having your library handy, I subbed in a test function that my compiler had no complaints about `static_cast`ing.  But point taken.

Answer (score 0):

> invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘Library*()’

In C++ it is illegal to cast between object and function pointer types (because e.g. they could be of different size).

Most compilers that support this as an extension will require you to use a `reinterpret_cast` or even a c-style cast.

Comment: static_cast<>() requires a type as an argument. The type provided is not a type at all.

Comment: @bert-jan: It is a type, try code like: `struct L; L*f();` it is just not a function pointer type, but a function type. See also template parameters like `std::function<L*()> f;`. Since any cast of that kind is a compiler extension, it is up to them whether it automatically decays to a pointer to function (like real functions do), or not. Depending on how his compiler implements such an extension, making it a pointer-to-function may or may not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

"Library* ()" does not evaluate to a type. Try "Library * (*)()"