# Dynamic Function in Cpp

Tags: c++, function, dynamic

I have been working on a cpp project and I would like to make my function dynamically. 
I have a function which has a bout 9 options when I am running.

Let capital letter be a condition as boolean type, and small letter be a function. And let's assume that my function has its conditions(A-I) outside the function as a global scope. And the conditions would not be changed during runtime. It would be just set one time before running this function, and would not be changed during this function.

```
void Myfunction(){
if(A) a(); // I would not use else if or switch since I should check all conditions.
if(B) b();
...
if(I) i();
return;
}
```

And the function would be called in a infinite-looped manner

```
int main(void){
//Conditions A - I is declared here
while (1) Myfunction;
return 0;
}
```

I do know that using if statement is quite slow and also checking non-variable conditions is kind of nonsense. In order for me to save computing resources and save time while running this function, I would like to make my function dynamically. Meaning that if first checking its conditions (A-I) then the function decides which expression to use.

For example, if we have conditions A, B, C as true and all others(D - I) as false. 
I would like to make the function automatically become.

```
void Myfunction(){
a();
b();
c();
return;
}
```

I have searched the internet, however wasn't able to find any. 
I found some articles about templates in cpp however it was not the case I was looking for.

Thank you for reading this article.
Since I am quite a new to Stackoverflow, I might have made some mistakes in this post.
If there are anything in this post that is against Stackoverflow's rules, please please let me know. I would be more than happy to modify my post.

Thank you.

Comment: C++ code does not modify itself. If your function is coded to check several variables, that's what it will always do. The closest thing in C++ to something like this would be a template function with `if constexpr`s -- but I somehow doubt that you are, yet, familiar with this latest addition to C++, and whether or not this would even be applicable in this case. Capsule summary: C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your information. I would definitely check that out. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess, you're looking for code generation. This migh help, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016078/is-it-possible-to-create-a-function-dynamically-during-runtime-in-c

Comment: @Insaf Thanks, I think that was the one that I was looking for.

Comment: The answers to that question show some ways of generating code at runtime but it is almost certainly not the solution to whatever problem you're solving and there are many reasons not to use them in actual useful code.

Comment: @BessieTheCow I would be fixing the code structure as well. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @Insaf I would downvote your comment if that was a thing. The linked question is not intended to provide actual useful code and it certainly won't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: No, it's not about the code structure. The methods to generate code at runtime presented in the question that Insaf linked to are just there to prove it's possible. Don't actually use them in real code. Again, this is not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Sorry for that. I didn't go through that link actually, I didn't have time when I was posting that comment. And we actually do code generation(using LLVM) to optimize some hotspots in code. My friends had done that for their project, but I don't know the details. I just wanted to provide some options for the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a solution using function templates.

The two main functions are `GetMyFunction()` and `MyFunctionTemplate()`.

`MyFunctionTemplate()` is a function template which would accept all of your expected params as bool template arguments(Non-type Template Arguments).

`GetMyFunction()` function would return pointer to the required specialization of `MyFunctionTemplate()` during run time.

`GetMyFunction()` also does one more thing, it must check for all of the combinations of the params, and return the corresponding function.

These `MyFunctionTemplate()` specialization would be created during compile time, and I believe those *if()* checks within `MyFunctionTemplate()` would be removed since those are time compile-time constants(Someone please confirm this).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void aFunc() { cout << "in a()" << endl; }
void bFunc() { cout << "in b()" << endl; }
void cFunc() { cout << "in c()" << endl; }
void dFunc() { cout << "in d()" << endl; }

template <bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d>
void MyFunctionTemplate()
{
    if (a) aFunc();
    if (b) bFunc();
    if (c) cFunc();
    if (d) dFunc();
}

void (*GetMyFunction(bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d))()
{
    if (a && b && c && d)
        return &MyFunctionTemplate<true, true, true, true>;
    if (a && b && c && !d)
        return &MyFunctionTemplate<true, true, true, false>;
    // And all other combinations follows....
}

int main(void)
{
    // Conditions A - I is declared here
    bool a = true, b = true, c = true, d = true;
    // auto MyFunction = GetMyFunction(a, b, c, d);
    void (*MyFunction)(void) = GetMyFunction(a, b, c, d);
    MyFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know how it goes.


Please note, `auto` keyword requires at least c++11 compiler. I've updated the answer to support older compilers

Comment: The code works fine for me. Also, I was inspired by the function pointer, so I am looking for another way to solve my problem as well! Thank you again for you time!

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution to my project using Function Pointers.
First I made my functions as and then saved those function pointers to an function pointer array. While saving those function pointers to function pointer array, I counted how many items would be saved in my function pointer array. So by using those counted value, I can iterate each element of my function array. Actually all my functions were in a class. so my functions were actually member functions.

In order for me to use my member function pointers, I needed to make a struct type of function pointer. And also declare a new function pointer variable in my class named CC to use it in its whole class scope.

```
typedef void(CC::FunctionPointers)();
FunctionPointers* FunctionPointerArray;
FunctionPointerArray = (FunctionPointers*)malloc(sizeof(FunctionPointers) * 4); // I will just say 4 conditions right ere. 
// Malloc-ing the FunctionPointers type can be possible, or there is another option 
// like making direct array (Both two are the same in terms of operation)
```

And, then I have function declaration and definition in my class named CC.

```
void aFunc() { cout << "in a()" << endl; }
void bFunc() { cout << "in b()" << endl; }
void cFunc() { cout << "in c()" << endl; }
void dFunc() { cout << "in d()" << endl; }
```

Then I make the function pointer array assignment member function. And lets save this returned value as `totalIterCounts`

```
int GenerateFunctionPointers(void){
    if(a) FunctionPointerArray[0] = &CC::aFunc();
    if(b) FunctionPointerArray[1] = &CC::bFunc();
    if(c) FunctionPointerArray[2] = &CC::cFunc();
    if(d) FunctionPointerArray[3] = &CC::dFunc();
    return a + b + c + d; // To set exact iteration counts;
}
```

Then When I need to call my functions, I will make this loop to call my functions.

```
void callFunctions(){
for (int i = 0 ; i < totalIterCounts ; i++){
    (this->*FunctionPointerArray[i])();
}
```

So in summary my whole class would be something like this.

```
class CC{
Public:
    typedef void(CC::FunctionPointers)();
    FunctionPointers* FunctionPointerArray = NULL;
    // I do know that using non-variable in malloc is kind of meaningless.
    int totalIterCounts; // To count how many iterations I need.

    CC(){
        totalIterCounts = GenerateFunctionPointers();
    }

    void aFunc() { cout << "in a()" << endl; }
    void bFunc() { cout << "in b()" << endl; }
    void cFunc() { cout << "in c()" << endl; }
    void dFunc() { cout << "in d()" << endl; }

    int GenerateFunctionPointers(void){
        FunctionPointerArray = (FunctionPointers*)malloc(sizeof(FunctionPointers) * 4) 
        //I have not initialized every element here, Assigning NULL would be safer.
        if(a) FunctionPointerArray[0] = &CC::aFunc();
        if(b) FunctionPointerArray[1] = &CC::bFunc();
        if(c) FunctionPointerArray[2] = &CC::cFunc();
        if(d) FunctionPointerArray[3] = &CC::dFunc();
        return a + b + c + d; // To set exact iteration counts;
    }

    void CallFunctions(){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < totalIterCounts ; i++){
        (this->*FunctionPointerArray[i])();
    }
}
```

And the function `CallFunctions()` can be called from outside in the future.
This solution worked for me last night. Special thanks to everyone who helped me with this question!

This is my first time with Answering my own question in Stackoverflow, so I might have some problems in this answer. Please let me know if I should modify or edit somethings. Again Thanks alot.